# Uso e significato di "circa" in questa frase

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, prepositions, adverbs

Nel racconto *Il pugno chiuso*, di Arrigo Boito, ho letto la frase seguente (grassetto mio):

> Vidi un gruppo ululante di cenciosi arruffati in terra **circa** sul luogo dove avevo gittato il *kopiec*.

Non sono sicura di capire del tutto bene il ruolo di questo "circa" che appare nel brano. In particolare, la combinazione "circa sul" che appare nel testo mi risulta strana. Comunque, la presenza della preposizione "sul" mi fa interprere che "circa" in questa frase sia un avverbio e non una preposizione (ma potrei sbagliarmi).

Di tutte le accezioni di ["circa" che ho trovato sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/circa), ho pensato che quella che avesse senso in questo contesto fosse la numero 2, "quasi, su per giù": quelle persone erano "quasi sul luogo" o "su per giù sul luogo" dove il narratore aveva gettato il *kopiec* (una moneta), cioè erano molto vicino a quel posto o si trovavano in quel posto in modo aprossimativo.

Tuttavia, mi è sembrato capire dal dizionario che "circa" con questo significato si usi soltanto con numeri, in espressioni come, per esempio:

> - *ci saranno circa dieci km*
> - *dieci km circa*
> - *tremila abitanti, o circa*.

È veramente così? O si usa anche "circa" col significato di "quasi, su per giù" con espressioni che non hanno a che vedere con una quantità?

Quello che appare nella frase sopra citata,
si tratta di un uso arcaico di "circa" o si adopera anche in questo modo nell'italiano di oggi?

Potresti aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

---

**Aggiornamento:**

Nei commenti si è menzionato che il valore di "circa" nella frase di questa domanda potrebbe corrispondere all'accezione numero 1 del Treccani, cioè, si tratterebbe di una preposizione col significato di "intorno a", riferito a luogo (uso arcaico di "circa"), come  nell'esempio di Dante, *Paradiso*  XII, 19-20:

> così di quelle sempiterne rose 
>                 volgìensi circa noi le due ghirlande

Tuttavia, personalmente, mi sembra strano che dopo una preposizione equivalente a "intorno a" si usi la preposizione "su" (ma posso essere completamente sbagliata). Quello che mi rende difficile questa interpretazione è la combinazione "circa sul" che appare nel testo: si potrebbe dire "intorno a sul luogo"? Ma, come si è anche detto, potrebbe trattarsi di qualche uso proprio del linguaggio ottocentesco. È così?

---

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000181.jpg) ho trovato "circa a" e "circa di", quindi qualche uso (immagino nel passato) della combinazione "circa su" sembra anche plausibile.

Comment: Si può anche dire "circa mezzanotte", "circa la metà", comuni, e anche "capire di più circa una cosa". A volte si usa col significato di *intorno*.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  "Intorno" in che senso? E cosa significa "di più circa"?

Comment: @Hachi:  Sì, questo uso di "circa" come preposizione l'avevo visto: è l'accezione 1 del Treccani. Ma, nel caso della frase della domanda, non mi sembra abbia molto senso seguito dalla preposizione "sul". Avrebbe senso se fosse "... circa il luogo ...".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: "La metà" e "mezzanotte" sono infatti anche espressioni con numeri.

Comment: @charo "metà" e "mezzanotte" *non sono* numeri. Che ne dici di "circa all'ora del tè", o "Circa/all'incirca in quel momento"? Fidati.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: "metà" e "mezza" sono numeri. Le altre espressioni con "circa" non le conosco bene: tra l'altro, è per questo che ho posto la domanda.

Comment: Comunque "circa sul luogo" è legittimo. Vuole dire "sopra a, grosso modo, quel luogo". E ribadisco che metà non è un numero, puoi dire "la metà di sinistra", "la metà più grossa", "la seconda metà del 900", "a metà del percorso" eccetera.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:   Non ho messo mai in dubbio che sia legittimo. Se scrivo "metà" nel modo 1/2 o nel modo 50% oppure 0,5 ti sembrerebbe più un numero?

Comment: Vuol dire “intorno al luogo”. È il significato etimologico di *circa* dal latino, stessa radice di *circus* (da cui *circulus*).

Comment: @charo, è brutto scrivere "ho 1/2 faccia abbronzata", e ancor peggio sarebbe "ho 0,5 moltiplicato la mia faccia abbronzata". Riguardo alla legittimità di "circa sul", c'è un tuo commento qui sopra che solleva il dubbio: scrivi ad Hachi "non ha molto senso ... avrebbe senso se". Invece ha senso così com'è.

Comment: @egreg: Ma "intorno al luogo" non sarebbe "circa il luogo" (come nell'esempio di Dante, che non ha nessuna preposizione dopo "circa")? Come ho detto nella domanda, quello che personalmente mi sembra difficile d'interpretare è la combinazione "circa sul". Se avesse trovato l'espressione "circa il luogo" non avrei posto la domanda.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: È anche brutto scrivere "ho 1 fratello e 1 sorella" e sono numeri lo stesso. Quel commento era per dire che la interpretazione di questo "circa" come avverbio (e non come preposizione) mi sembra più plausibile.

Comment: @Charo Nel linguaggio attuale la preposizione è insensata, ma si sta discutendo di un autore ottocentesco.

Comment: Va bene, @egreg: infatti questo è una delle cose che chiedo nella domanda.

Comment: @egreg "circa sul luogo" secondo me non è insensato, forse *circa* in questo caso non ha valore preposizionale. Altri modi per dirlo sarebbero "più o meno sul luogo", "sull'intorno del luogo", "grosso modo sul luogo", "sul luogo dove grosso modo...". Se i concetti da esprimere sono due (circa e sul) non vedo molte possibilità, o si usano due semplici parole oppure si usa un giro di parole.

Answer (score 2):

La parola circa ha il duplice ruolo di preposizione ed avverbio. Come preposizione è una derivazione diretta dal latino, significa "intorno a", ed il suo uso è arcaico. In questo caso, invece, è usata come avverbio, con il significato di "quasi". "Quasi" è un sinonimo di "circa", presente in tutti i dizionari dei sinonimi e dei contrari. Se leggi "quasi sul luogo dove", sembra suonare meglio, ma anche con "circa" non è sbagliato, forse solo poco usato. A volte, in casi come questo, si usa "all'incirca", che è un semplice rafforzativo di circa. In ogni caso, "circa", "all'incirca", "quasi", "pressappoco", "suppergiù", ecc. sono tutti sinonimi che indicano una approssimazione, quando non si conosce o non si vuole indicare un dato preciso, sia esso un numero, un luogo, una data o altro.

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @Massimo. Soltanto un chiarimento. Posso tranquillamente dire (in modo naturale per l'italiano attuale) qualcosa come, per esempio, "si trovava circa sulla perpendicolare della nostra posizione" o "siamo circa arrivati a destinazione"? O si tratta invece di un uso arcaico di "circa"?

Comment: Sì, entrambe le frasi sono corrette e non arcaiche, la prima frase è assolutamente usata anche oggi, mentre per la seconda, in generale, si tende ad usare maggiormente "quasi"